# Issue updating Terraform resource in custom provider using Terraform Plugin Framework

Tags: go, terraform-provider

I'm currently developing a Terraform provider using the [Terraform Plugin Framework](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/plugin). My challenge revolves around updating a resource A that contains an array of resource B. In my API design, when I want to add a resource B to the object's list, I use a route that returns the modified resource A.

In the Terraform code, I would like to have two resources, for example, resource_a and resource_b, so that I can represent them like this:

```
resource "resource_a" "main" {
    // …
}

resource "resource_b" "main" {
    object_a_id = resource_a.main.id
    // …
}
```

The issue I'm facing is that when I follow this approach, in the creation method of resource B, I receive the modified resource A, but I'm unsure how to update terraform resource A via resource B implementation code.

I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to handle this scenario effectively.

sincerely